# Can't resolve archive.raspberrypi.org. can't install anything

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I have raspberry pi 3. And I can't even update it because when I do the update screen is held at archive.raspberrypi.org. I tried to open it in browser, the site is down. What should I do?

And yeah it is perfectly online.

Comment: Is your internet connection set up and working?  Try running `ping www.google.com` in a terminal and see if you get a response.  If not, then your internet connection is not up.

Answer (score 4):

temporarily disabling ipv6 solved my issue (temporarily)

```
apt -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update
```

Answer (score 0):

From my point, the site is online. Are you sure your Raspberry is connected to the internet?

Also http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/archive.raspberrypi.org says it is online.

**Edit:**

Check your /etc/hosts file for entries which change the location of the Domain in question.

Comment: It is perfectly online. I can access internet on my pi

Comment: Strange, did the problem solve it self (maybe through reboot)? Otherwise check your /etc/hosts file, maybe some script messed it up.

Comment: Everything is fine., I think the problem is with me only,,, like when i try to open http://raspberrypi.org/ It fails to open everytime. Every other website on internet is totally accessible but i dont know why this website only?

Comment: This may sound trivial, but you double checked for typos? Like ras**bp**erry.org?
This sure won't affect apt-get, as the tool does not make typos ;-) Can you open the page on a computer in the same network? Maybe a router or other device is messing with the communication

Answer (score 0):

Check the storage of your sd card. If you have a lot of information on it, it might slow down or stop working. If you have a lot of information, you have 2 options:

1. Remove unwanted information
2. Install a fresh OS image on it